# Include digits in cucumber feature files as strings?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am writing cucumber tests that specify certain numbers should be in certain places of the data as strings.  So I am trying to run this:

myFeature.feature

```
...
Then this segment should equal 01
```

mySteps.java

```
@Then("^Then this segment should equal 01$")
public void myThenStep() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

But what cucumber is telling me to use is this:

```
@Then("^Then this segment should equal (\\d+)$")
public void myThenStep(int arg1) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

I am not trying to include arguments, I am trying to assert that the string I got equals 01.  How do I do this?  It seems really simple, but I can't find a way to escape that number.  Thanks!

Comment: Related post - [How to write numbers in cucumber scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32475031/465053)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want pass in the 01 from the feature to your step but instead use it as test, this should work

```
@Then("^Then this segment should equal 01$")
public void myThenStep() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

If you want to pass in the string from your feature file, you can do something like

```
@Then("^Then this segment should equal (.*)$")
public void myThenStep(String arg1) {
    // arg1 will be "01" in your test
    // Do stuff
}
```